# Android - JSoup Select

Tags: android, select, jsoup

I'm having some trouble with the JSoup library, specifically when trying too select the text inside the  tags. The output should be 'HELLO WORLD'

I would have thought doc.select("div.sub").get(0); would do the trick but it doesn't return anything. Is there a method I've ignorantly missed?

My code:

```
final String url = "http://www.my123url.com,";
Element myText; 
Document doc;   

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8",
                url);
        myText = doc.select("div.sub").get(0);
                    System.out.println("Text is: " + myText.text();
                    return myText.text();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("The exception caught is: " + e);
                   }
```

The code I'm trying to scrape:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="main-row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="sub" style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 27px;">
            <cufon alt="HELLO" class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 45px; height: 18px;">
                <canvas height="28" style="width: 75px; height: 24px; top: -2px; left: -10px;" width="77"></canvas>
                <cufontext>HELLO
                </cufontext>
             </cufon>
            <cufon alt="WORLD " class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 20px; height: 18px;">
                <canvas height="28" style="width: 63px; height: 20px; top: -5px; left: -10px;" width="63"></canvas>
                <cufontext>WORLD
               </cufontext>
           </cufon>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text `HELLO` and `WORLD` are deeper in the children. You should get them separately:

```
doc.select("div.sub cufontext").get(0).text() + " " + doc.select("div.sub cufontext").get(1).text()
```